# How to find the substring between two string?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6, ios4

I have a string "hi how are... you"

I want to find the Sub-string after how and before you..

How to do this in objective c?

Comment: What you tried? Or, are you checking if some one knows here?

Comment: Did you search before asking? What have you tried?

Comment: i checked and i tried some methods abut its not working..

Comment: i checked .. but its showing a null value but when i print the string its showing the substring Present..

Comment: "This question is unlikely to help any future visitors", hmm almost 5k views in 2 years.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Find the range of the two strings and return the substring in between:

```
NSString *s = @"hi how are... you";

NSRange r1 = [s rangeOfString:@"how"];
NSRange r2 = [s rangeOfString:@"you"];
NSRange rSub = NSMakeRange(r1.location + r1.length, r2.location - r1.location - r1.length);
NSString *sub = [s substringWithRange:rSub];
```

Comment: I felt sad while seeing you answering for this childish question. You have a standard here. you should leave these question for young StackOverFlowers ;)

Comment: @AnoopVaidya It's equally sad that these young stackoverflowers only managed to give wrong or meaningless/incomplete answers.

Comment: @H2CO3 : thanks for your help but its showing subString = (null).. what i am doing is i am taking a html page and finding a substring.. but when i see the html page its showing the string and if i use any of the substring finding method its showing "null".. what would be the problem can u please tell me..

Comment: @Raju Hard to tell without your actual code and data. Can be anything from a typo in the searched string to a memory management mistake.

Comment: Is there any swift version...?

Comment: Swift 2.0 ver:         let s: NSString = "hi how are... you" as NSString
        let r1: NSRange = s.rangeOfString("how")
        let r2: NSRange = s.rangeOfString("you")
        let rSub: NSRange = NSMakeRange(r1.location + r1.length, r2.location - r1.location - r1.length)
        let sub: String = s.substringWithRange(rSub)

Comment: it fails if I want substring between two strings which are equal

Answer (score 11):

You could use the method of NSString `substringWithRange`

Example

```
NSString *string=@"hi how are you";
NSRange searchFromRange = [string rangeOfString:@"how"];
NSRange searchToRange = [string rangeOfString:@"you"];
NSString *substring = [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(searchFromRange.location+searchFromRange.length, searchToRange.location-searchFromRange.location-searchFromRange.length)];
NSLog(@"subs=%@",substring); //subs= are
```

Answer (score 0):

use `SubstringTOIndex` & `SubstringFromIndex` functions of `NSString`. Where `SubstringFromIndex` gives you the `string` from the index which you passed & `SubstringToIndex` function gives you the `string` upto the index which you passed.

Also try `substringWithRange` function which returns you the `string` between the range which you passed.

Comment: There is nothing in this answer that explains how to find the needed ranges.

Comment: @rmaddy I just given the names of functions which are helpful for getting the substring. By using this functions, we can get the substring, so no need of providing the detailed answer.

Comment: The point is to find the indexes at runtime. Using just the methods you propose will require that the index be hardcoded. If that's all that needed to be done then there would not have been a question.

Answer (score -1):

Use `substringWithRange`...

```
NSString* substring = [originalString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(3, originalString.length-6)];
```